# JSON Post request from Codename One

Tags: json, codenameone

I have been struggling with this for the past couple days and I think I tried every example I could find on the internet.  I'm trying to sign in to my REST and get back the Authorization code for ongoing communication.  It works when using Postman

----Taken from Postman Generate Code Snippit----

```
POST /api/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: baffa067-c2a0-4d5c-b321-348682227195
{
    "username": "Test",
    "password": "Testpw"
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

and it returns

```
{"accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ0Mjc4MTE5LCJleHAiOjE1NDQ4ODI5MTl9.qNQ7MIIsWpYQdeje6Ox88KR9AdNGCSiffjyk__nrdWvP7yoy4Ukk05ZQUISVptOIoBpahFT1OHf_MXVQnW5Izg","tokenType":"Bearer"}
```

My code in my CodenameOne project is:

```
 public void onloginActionEvent(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {
              JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
              try {
                  ConnectionRequest post = new ConnectionRequest(){
                        @Override
                        protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                            os.write(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void postResponse() {                             
                        }
                    };
                    json.put("username", "Test");
                    json.put("password", "Testpw");

                  post.setUrl("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signin");
                  post.setPost(true);
                  post.setContentType("application/json");
                  post.addArgument("body", json.toString());
                  String bodyToString = json.toString();
                  NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(post);
                  Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(post.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
```

When using the CodenameOne Simulator Network Monitor has the following result

```
URL: http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signin

Type: Post

Request:BodyPart: {"password":"Test","username":"Testpw"}


Request:Request Headers: User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1]
Content-Type=[application/json]

Response:Body: blank

Response: Response Headers: Transfer-Encoding=[chunked]
X-Frame-Options=[DENY]
null=[HTTP/1.1 200]
Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate]
X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff]
Expires=[0]
Pragma=[no-cache]
X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block]
Date=[Sat, 08 Dec 2018 14:14:54 GMT]
Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override `readResponse` without calling `super`. This overrides the default behavior of reading the data. You can just remove that method or write the logic for reading the JSON within that method.